# Некорректно отображается стиль

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Поставил Блок «Поделиться» на сайте
Но стиль отображается неверно. 
Маркированный список отображается с маркерами-картинками наследуемый с сайта
[image: некорректное отображение стилей кнопок]
Добавил код в стили, но это не помогает

```
.ya-share2 ul{
list-style-type: none !important;
list-style: none !important;
list-style-image: none !important;}
.ya-share2__list_direction_horizontal {background: none !important;}
.ya-share2__item {background: none !important;}
```

Comment: Напишите какой стиль применяет браузер, посмотрите в инструментах разработчика. И посмотрите еще вариант с :before и :after на li

Comment: Спасибо! :before и :after - это помогло